# Redirect link problems using htaccess

Tags: http-status-code-404

I have made an opencart store on a subdomain, and I was wondering if there is any way to redirect pages cause when I replace the store word to anything it gives me `404 eror page not found`.

ex: http://XXX.XXX/store -----------> http://XXX.XXX/mobile (i got the 404 error)

And how I can get rid from the 404 error on opencart 3 store?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

where `example.com` is the old domain and `example.net` is the new one

please share your current .htaccess file for more details

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22358754)

Comment: ... what would be the right answer here? I can't comment, nor I can't ask for more details... so I just not help? is that the right way to act?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer... you can wait for an explanation from OP. But if none is given there is nothing you can do yet... :)

Comment: I know, but I can't comment yet... thats the issue. anyhow the only way to help him is to see the current htaccess because the issue is not in the redirect but probably in the settings of the RewriteBase. so will wait for his reply.

Comment: it looks like he replayed in an answer witch is not good... it should be an edit to the question...